# How to stop unwanted UIButton animation on title change?

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios7, uibutton, uikit

In iOS 7 my UIButton titles are animating in and out at the wrong time - late. This problem does not appear on iOS 6. I'm just using:

```
[self setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I would prefer this happens instantly and without a blank frame. This blink is especially distracting and draws attention away from other animations.

Comment: We're experiencing this as well. Not sure if it's a iOS7 bug or something we should fix.

Comment: Try,[self.button setHighlighted:NO];

Comment: Thanks for these ideas. I tried setHighlighted:NO, but no luck there. I am able to reduce the blink by placing setTitle inside: [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0f animations:^{ ... }];

Comment: You can use this workaround in some cases: `self.button.titleLabel.text = text`. But this don't resize label frame and don't work with UIControlStates correctly

Comment: That's a clever workaround. I'll play with this and see what happens, unfortunately I'm using UIControlStates.

Comment: only answer from dubenko worked for me: stackoverflow.com/questions/18946490/how-to-stop-unwanted-uibutton-animation-on-title-change#23212964

Comment: Using custom UIButton type solved my problem.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

This works for custom buttons:

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

For system buttons you need to add this before re-enabling animations (thank you @Klaas):

```
[_button layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: This fix eliminates the blink completely - nice.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work. Neither does performWithoutAnimation

Comment: Ok, so the fix that worked in the end was to leave the original UIButton text blank so that when I set it with code it doesn't trigger the animation.

Comment: This works only if you set the button's type to custom, as per this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/20718467/62.

Comment: As of iOS 7.1 I had to add `[_button layoutIfNeeded];`

Comment: @LironYahdav if you have the button type set to UIButtonTypeCustom, then this answer is not required.

Comment: @Klaas post it as answer. It works for system buttons!

Comment: @orkenstein Maybe we are better of when Jacob adds it to his answer?

Comment: even adding layoutifneeded doesn't work for me (ios 8 xcode 6, custom keyboard extension)

Comment: layoutIfNeeded works on iOS8 iff you do layout inside no animations block (i.e. disable animations, set title, layout, enable animations)

Comment: Simple just Change button type from system to custom

Comment: @SidShah when? Add more info to your comment

Comment: this worked for me [UIView setAnimationsEnabled: NO];
    [self.button setTitle: text forState: UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.button layoutIfNeeded];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled: YES];

Comment: Adding a layoutIfNeeded in the case of using multiple buttons in a view adds a *significant* performance overhead, beware.

Answer (score 290):

Use the `performWithoutAnimation:` method and then force layout to happen immediately instead of later on.

```
[UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{
  [self.myButton setTitle:text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [self.myButton layoutIfNeeded];
}];
```

Comment: This works as well as the accepted answer, but seems nicer because it is more encapsulated - it is impossible to forget to add the [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES], or for it to get removed down the track.

Comment: It works for system buttons if you call `[button layoutIfNeeded];` inside the block.

Comment: BTW, for system buttons, layoutIfNeed should be called **after** text changed

Comment: This is the best solution! Cheers

Comment: This is correct one for me. It's most voted and on 6th place. Nice...

Answer (score 109):

In Swift you can use :

```
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.someButtonButton.setTitle(newTitle, forState: .normal)
    self.someButtonButton.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: This was by far the easiest method. And thank you for including a swift answer btw

Comment: Best answer for Swift!

Comment: Had an annoying bug where changing a UIButton title while offscreen would cause weird animation timings with interactivePopGestureRecognizer and this solved it.  I still think it's a bug with the OS though

Comment: Strange that .layoutIfNeeded() has to be called, but I tested it both ways in Swift 5 and it definitely still animates without it.

Comment: Not really. If you don't call `layoutIfNeeded()` then the button is flagged as needing to be redrawn but this won't happen until the next layout pass, which will be outside the `performWithoutAnimation`

Answer (score 97):

Change button type to custom form interface builder.

[image]

This worked for me.

Comment: Best solution! Thank you.

Comment: But this also disable animation on click button. I want only disable animation on showing button.

Comment: This works if you don't care about the animation when the button is tapped.

Comment: I've had a couple of buttons set like this and obviously this is the most elegant answer for my case. Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 62):

**Please note :**

when "*buttonType*" of _button is **"UIButtonTypeSystem"**, below code is **invalid**：

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

when "*buttonType*" of _button is **"UIButtonTypeCustom"**, above code is **valid**.

Comment: Can't believe how much time I spent before figuring out you just need to change the button type... ugh...

Comment: Works without any code. Change only buttons type and it'll work.

Answer (score 56):

Starting in iOS 7.1 the only solution that worked for me was initializing the button with type `UIButtonTypeCustom`.

Comment: This is the most sensible approach for anyone that doesn't require UIButtonTypeSystem.

Comment: This ended up working best for me, I just created a CUSTOM button and made it look and highlight like a system button. Can hardly see the difference but you don't have that delay.

Answer (score 23):

## Swift 5

```
myButton.titleLabel?.text = "title"
myButton.setTitle("title", for: .normal)
```

Comment: No idea why this works but it does and it's the cleanest solution. UIKit is weird.

Comment: no, its not a clean solution, but its quite dirty, as this may change with any iOS

Comment: @NathanHosselton see dubenko's answer on Apr 22'14. "in first we change title for button, then resize button for this title"

Comment: This is a workaround which can stop to work in any new versions of UIKit. UIButton of type "system" animates title update when new title is different from previous one. If you find it awkward then you should use a button of type "custom"

Answer (score 18):

so i find worked solution:

```
_logoutButton.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Logout",);
[_logoutButton setTitle:_logoutButton.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

in first we change title for button, then resize button for this title

Comment: I use the same workaround. The accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Comment: This causes the title to flash twice, at least with iOS 8.

Comment: This works for me in both 7.1 and 8.1 without flashing. Simple and effective.

Comment: Works perfectly in iOS 11, although I had to use the same string again for the second line (using the button label's title caused it to blink).

Answer (score 18):

UIButton with `system` type has implicit animation on `setTitle(_:for:)`. You can fix it two different ways:

1. Set the button type to `custom`, either from code or Interface Builder:

```swift
let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
```

[image]

2. Disable animation from code:

```swift
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
    button.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 14):

I’ve made a Swift extension to do this:

```
extension UIButton {
    func setTitleWithoutAnimation(title: String?) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

        setTitle(title, forState: .Normal)

        layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Works for me on iOS 8 and 9, with `UIButtonTypeSystem`.

(The code is for Swift 2, Swift 3 and Objective-C should be similar)

Comment: Not going to use it now but very handy to have around!

Answer (score 14):

Set the button type to UIButtonTypeCustom and it'll stop flashing

Comment: How can all those workaround "solutions" have so many upvotes when this simple answer must solve this issue 99% of the time...

Answer (score 12):

Set UIButton type as Custom. That should remove fade in and out animations.

Comment: This should have more upvotes! Works perfectly and disables the animation at the root cause, instead of these other workarounds.

Answer (score 9):

Usually simply setting the button type to Custom works for me, but for other reasons I needed to subclass UIButton and set the button type back to the default (System), so the blinking reappeared.

Setting `UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)` before changing the title and then to true again after that didn't avoid the blinking for me, no matter if I called `self.layoutIfNeeded()` or not.

This, and only this in the following exact order, worked for me with iOS 9 and 10 beta:

1) Create a subclass for UIButton (don't forget to set the custom class for the button in the Storyboard too).

2) Override `setTitle:forState:` as follows:

```
override func setTitle(title: String?, forState state: UIControlState) {

    UIView.performWithoutAnimation({

        super.setTitle(title, forState: state)

        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

In Interface Builder, you can leave the button type to System, no need to change it to Custom Type for this approach to work.

I hope this helps someone else, I've struggled for so long with the annoying blinking buttons that I hope to avoid it to others ;)

Comment: Don't forget `layoutIfNeeded()` :]

Answer (score 6):

You can simply create Custom button and it will stop animate while changing the title.

```
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setTitle:@"the title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

you also can do it in Storyboard checkbox: 
select the button in storyboard -> select the attributes inspector (fourth from left side) -> in the 'Type' drop down menu, select 'Custom' instead of 'System' that was probably selected.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 version of Xhacker Liu answer**

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
extension UIButton {
    func setTitleWithOutAnimation(title: String?) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

        setTitle(title, for: .normal)

        layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can remove the animations from from the title label's layer:

```
    [[[theButton titleLabel] layer] removeAllAnimations];
```

Comment: I went through all the answers. This one is the best.

Comment: It still blinks but it's better.

Comment: THIS SHOULD BE THE ANSWER.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually set the title outside of an animation block, just be sure to call `layoutIfNeeded()` inside a performWithoutAnimation:

```
button1.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
button2.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
button3.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.button1.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.button2.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.button3.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

If you have a bunch of buttons, consider just calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the super view:

```
button1.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
button2.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
button3.setTitle("abc", forState: .Normal)
UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A convenient extension for animated button title change in Swift that plays nicely with the default implementation:

```
import UIKit

extension UIButton {
  /// By default iOS animated the title change, which is not desirable in reusable views
  func setTitle(_ title: String?, for controlState: UIControlState, animated: Bool = true) {
    if animated {
      setTitle(title, for: controlState)
    } else {
      UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)
      setTitle(title, for: controlState)
      layoutIfNeeded()
      UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Fogmeister
1. My answer is different
2. Up-to-date Swift syntax
3. Consistent with Apple's API for `UIButton`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that this workaround works with **UIButtonTypeSystem** as well but will only work if the button is **enabled** for some reason.

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
[_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

So you'll have to add these if you need the button to be disabled when setting its title.

```
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
_button.enabled = YES;
[_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
_button.enabled = NO;
[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
```

(iOS 7, Xcode 5)

Comment: Just confirmed that this workaround no longer works on iOS 7.1.

Comment: don't suppose you've found a solution for 7.1?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen couldn't find any working solutions for **UIButtonTypeSystem**. I had to use **UIButtonTypeCustom**.

Comment: Since 7.1, you'll need to apply title changes to all states, setting it just for the normal state no longer applies. `[_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateDisabled]`

Answer (score 0):

Combining above great answers results in following workaround for **UIButtonTypeSystem**:

```
if (_button.enabled)
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    [_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
else // disabled
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
    _button.enabled = YES;
    [_button setTitle:@"title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _button.enabled = NO;
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the ugly animation problem when changing button titles in view controllers within a UITabBarController.
The titles that were originally set in the storyboard showed up for a short while before fading into their new values.

I wanted to iterate through all subviews and use the button titles as keys to get their localized values with NSLocalizedString, such as;

```
for(UIView *v in view.subviews) {

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)v;
        NSString *newTitle = NSLocalizedString(btn.titleLabel.text, nil);
        [btn setTitle:newTitle];
    }

}
```

I found out that what's triggering the animation is really the call to btn.titleLabel.text.
So to still make use of the storyboards and have the components dynamically localized like this I make sure to set every button's Restoration ID (in Identity Inspector) to the same as the title and use that as key instead of the title;

```
for(UIView *v in view.subviews) {

    if ([v isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *btn = (UIButton*)v;
        NSString *newTitle = NSLocalizedString(btn.restorationIdentifier, nil);
        [btn setTitle:newTitle];
    }

}
```

Not ideal, but works..

Answer (score 0):

The Xhacker Liu extension converted to Swift 3 :

```
extension UIButton {
    func setTitleWithoutAnimation(title: String?) {
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(false)

        setTitle(title, for: .normal)

        layoutIfNeeded()
        UIView.setAnimationsEnabled(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got it to work with a combination of answers:

```
[[[button titleLabel] layer] removeAllAnimations];

    [UIView performWithoutAnimation:^{

        [button setTitle:@"Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }];
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe generating 2 animations and 2 buttons is a better solution, to avoid the problem that is appearing with animating and changing the text of a button?

I created a second uibutton and generated 2 animation, this solution works with no hickups.

```
    _button2.hidden = TRUE;
    _button1.hidden = FALSE;

    CGPoint startLocation = CGPointMake(_button1.center.x, button1.center.y - 70);
    CGPoint stopLocation  = CGPointMake(_button2.center.x, button2.center.y- 70);


    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ _button2.center = stopLocation;} completion:^(BOOL finished){_button2.center = stopLocation;}];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{ _button1.center = startLocation;} completion:^(BOOL finished){_button1.center = startLocation;}];
```