# CoreMedia permissions error for TodayExtension

Tags: ios

I am currently passing data to my Today extension through UserDefaults and when I show up my Widget this error appears:

`Widget[50536:1416650] Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 45172: (null)`

It's funny because my widget it's actually getting the data so I don't fully understand what could be wrong in the implementation. Any guess ?

Comment: Did you look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091463/today-extension-failed-to-inherit-coremedia-permissions-from? It may help

Comment: I think this is because of you have to add appgroup, you need to same access identifier for your app and extension as well to shared data between them.

Comment: It's weird because I followed all the steps. Actually, my app and my widget shares the data properly but this error keeps showing up and my widget shows 'Unable to load' although when I am debugging I can see the data is passed through UserDefaults.