# CoreData in extension: how to use database in shared group

Tags: swift, core-data, bundle, persistent-storage

Trying to use `CoreData` in Keyboard Extension. I guess that database file must be in one place for both - extension and containing app. That place is app group. I made it in Apple account. I set using it in both app and extension (checkbox in Singing and Capabilities). But it s not the same in app and extension or I misunderstood something. Here`s some code.

In my app I made a lazy var to store `DB` file `URL` in `AppDelegate` file:

```
   lazy var secureAppGroupPersistentStoreURL : URL = {
       let fileManager = FileManager.default
       let groupDirectory = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.xxxxx")!
       //xxxxx - is my real bundle identificator
       return groupDirectory.appendingPathComponent("SharedData.sqlite")
    }()
```

I think it must pointing to file in shared folder. Then I create `PersistentContaner` like this

```
   lazy var testPersistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "testDataShare")
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription(url: secureAppGroupPersistentStoreURL)
        description.shouldInferMappingModelAutomatically = true
        description.shouldMigrateStoreAutomatically = true
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]

        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
```

I using `NSPersistentStoreDescription` to set DB filename. At least I believe it works so:)
After that in my SceneDelegate file I use this container like this (my test entity is called Entity and has only one attribute called name):

```
//debug
    let testContext = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).testPersistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()
     if let keyboards = try? testContext.fetch(fetchRequest){
         print("fetch: \(keyboards.debugDescription)")
     }else{
         print("fetched nothin")
     }

    let testEntity = Entity(context: testContext)
    testEntity.name = "test from app"
    _ = try? testContext.save()
```

just for testing I insert one more object every time I start my app. It works fine for now. I getting debug info in console like this:

> fetch: [ (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e433bbae
>   ; data:
>   ),  (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e43fbbae
>   ; data:
>   ),  (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e43bbbae
>   ; data:
>   ),  (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e427bbae
>   ; data:
>   ),  (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e423bbae
>   ; data:
>   ),  (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e42fbbae
>   ; data:
>   ),  (entity: Entity; id:
>   0x9f53fc35e42bbbae
>   ; data: {
>       name = "test from app"; })]

I did the very same in my extension, added lazy var `secureAppGroupPersistentStoreURL`, created `PersistentContainer` to `KeyboardViewController` and trying to do the same fetch in `viewDidLoad()` but its doesn't show any results.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let context = self.testPersistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Entity> = Entity.fetchRequest()
    if let keyboards = try? context.fetch(fetchRequest){
        print("fetch: \(keyboards.debugDescription)")
    }else{
        print("fetched nothin")
    }
    //...
}
```

When I starts extension simulation it prints this:

> 2020-03-06 01:17:25.835412+0300 Keyboard[3482:275851] Failed to
>   inherit CoreMedia permissions from 3042: (null) 
>   fetch: []

I expect the objects I saved in app will be able to fetch in extension and vice versa.

What am I doing wrong with database file?

Comment: Does your keyboard extension has enabled full access ? If no, I am afraid you cannot access shared data, even save to UserDefaults between extensions and parent app.

Comment: @user3344236 yes it does. I know that I need it to share data.

Comment: oh yes! It was stupid but I forget to check full access again after selecting another device for simulation (or I reset simulation, not really sure how exactly I lost it). I was really sure it is on, but it wasn't. After I turned it on, I got my entities fetched. Post it like an answer and I'll give you a bounty.

Comment: by the way, I still getting message:
Failed to inherit CoreMedia permissions from 23131: (null)
Don't you know what is it?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26091463/today-extension-failed-to-inherit-coremedia-permissions-from  it is obvious related to  App Groups entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your keyboard extension has enabled full access. If no, I am afraid you cannot access shared data, even save to UserDefaults between extensions and parent app.

Comment: It helps. Every time you reset divice in simulation or start simulation on other device - this flag resets to false.
Sorry, the bounty has expired, I can't give you reward.

Comment: this dosen't help