# Is setTitle() function of UIButton asynchronous?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uikit

I have two variables `isLoading` and `isConnected` in a `UITableViewCell` class and the code is as below:

```
    var isConnected = false {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != isConnected {
                print("[op] isConnected: \(oldValue) -> \(isConnected)")
                updateActionButton()
            }
        }
    }
    private var isLoading = false {
        didSet {
            if oldValue != isLoading {
                print("[op] isLoading: \(oldValue) -> \(isLoading)")
                updateLoadingView()
            }
        }
    }
...
    private func updateActionButton() {
        print("[op] updateActionButton()")
        actionButton.setTitle(isConnected ? "Disconnect" : "Connect", for: .normal)
        actionButton.setTitleColor(isConnected ? .systemRed : .systemBlue, for: .normal)
        print("[op] \(isConnected ? "Disconnect" : "Connect") : \(actionButton.isHidden ? "hidden" : "show")")
    }
    private func updateLoadingView() {
        loadingIndicator.isHidden = !isLoading
        actionButton.isHidden = isLoading
        if isLoading {
            loadingIndicator.startAnimating()
        } else {
            loadingIndicator.stopAnimating()
        }
    }
```

The logic is very simple:

- When `isLoading == true`, the cell will display the `loadingIndicator` which is a `UIActivityIndicatorView`.
- When `isLoading == false`,  it will hides the `loadingIndicator` and show the `actionButton`.
- When the cell receives a notification, it will change the value of `isLoading` and `isConnected`, the code it triggers is:

```
isConnected = true
isLoading = false
```

The expected behavior is:

- step 1: The text of button change to `Disconnect`. (the button is hidden at this time)
- step 2: `loadingIndicator` is set to hidden and `actionButton` appears with text `Disconnect`.

However, what it really happens at step 2 is:

`actionButton` appears with text `Connect` and then the text changes to `Disconnect`.

And the console log is:

```
[op] isConnected: false -> true
[op] updateActionButton()
[op] Disconnect : hidden
[op] isLoading: true -> false
```

The order I got from console is correct, the `setTitle` function was called before `isLoading` changed to `false`, but I don't know why the text is still `Connect` when the `actionButton.isHidden` is set to `false`.

So I wonder is `setTitle` asynchronous (the function is not complete when `actionButton` is set to not hidden)? Or there is something wrong in my code logic to cause the unexpected behavior in step 2?

Comment: `setTitle(_,for:)` is synchronous, so you need to do more debugging: is the referenced button _really_ the button you expect to modify? (For example, test by changing the strings you assign to something completely different, set break points and look at the instance, etc.). Is there some other code that might change the button?

Comment: may be the button state is causing the issue. try to set state to .normal , .selected , .highlighted at same time.

Comment: Also , try to set title on main thread.

Comment: Another possibility is that the cell is accidentally reloaded, for example, if you have a reloadData somewhere in your code. A cell can also be reloaded upon scrolling, when it moves out and into the screen

Comment: Thank you all. I've managed to find the reason.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946490/how-to-stop-unwanted-uibutton-animation-on-title-change
Turns out this happened since iOS 7 but I've never encountered this since today. The button I create is a `system` type, so either I change it to a `custom` type or I use the solution in that question.